How to modify prompt in macOS terminal?
Stupid question, but how would I remove the following from my macOS terminal?
(xyz) abc@defgh~%

I want to get rid of (xyz). How would I do it?

Are you operating in a conda environment named "xyz" by any chance?

I don't know if how this is done on mac, but in bash the string of the prompt is a environment variable ($PS1). At least on Linux you can configure the prompt by modifying this var. Here is a link to the arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bash/Prompt_customization. Maybe you can find such a guide for mac

You can change the prompts, which are kept in the $PS1, $PS2, $PS3, and $PS4 environment variables, but only $PS1 is used to generate your command prompt. $PS1 is a formatting string, not plain text. It's described in the PROMPTING section of the man page for your shell. Do: man ${SHELL##*/} and search with /PROMPT.
